# Looping through a list and generating knockout components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

So I want to dynamically generate knockout components from an array of objects with properties.

Here is the html that will generate the components (apologies in advance for the terrible component name):

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: graphs">
               <y1vsy2graphs params=" graphTitle: $data.y1Title + ' vs ' + 
                                      $data.y2Title,
                                      y1Title: $data.y1Title,
                                      y2Title: $data.y2Title,
                                      tickInterval: $parent.tickInterval(),
                                      y1suffix: '',
                                      y2suffix: '',
                                      graphID: 'red',
                                      filter: $parent.filter(),
                                      selectedOption: 
                                      $parent.selectedOption(),
                                      url: 
                      Urls.get_ppc_dashboard_values(PageMeta.AccountToken)">
                </y1vsy2graphs> 
</div>
```

And here is the array it is looping through in the parent viewModel:

```
self.graphs = ko.observableArray([
{'y1Title': 'Cost', 'y1Data': self.datas()['Cost'],'y2Title':'ROI', 'y2Data': self.datas()['ROI']},
{'y1Title': 'Clicks','y1Data': self.datas()['Clicks'], 'y2Title': 'CPC', 'y2Data': self.datas()['CPC']},
{'y1Title': 'IMP','y1Data': self.datas()['IMP'], 'y2Title': 'CTR','y2Data':self.datas()['CTR']},
{'y1Title': 'Conv','y1Data': self.datas()['Conv'], 'y2Title': 'CPA', 'y2Data':self.datas()['CPA']},
{'y1Title': 'Conv','y1Data': self.datas()['Conv'],'y2Title': 'RPS', 'y2Data': self.datas()['RPS']}
]);
```

Currently my code does create the elements as shown in the developer tools:

[Developer-Tools:Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnOQc.png)

However I am not receiving any error messages from my y1vsy2graphs component. For that reason i'm having diffuculty identifying my problem.

Comment: When i place <div data-bind="text: y1Title"> </div> I get 5 graph titles rendered.

Comment: Did you correctly [register your component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#registering-custom-elements)?

Comment: Yes if i simply do 

` <y1vsy2graph params="graphTitle: 'Cost vs ROI',
                y1Title: 'ROI',
                y2Title: 'Cost',
                tickInterval: tickInterval,
                y1suffix: '',
                y2suffix: '',
                graphID: 'red',
                filter: filter,
                selectedOption: selectedOption,
                url: Urls.get_ppc_dashboard_values(PageMeta.AccountToken)">         
        </y1vsy2graph>
`

The graphs render fine. The loop is breaking it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: graphs">
  <div data-bind="component: { name: 'y1vsy2graphs', 
                               params: {
                                  graphTitle: $data.y1Title + ' vs ' + $data.y2Title,
                                  y1Title: $data.y1Title,
                                  y2Title: $data.y2Title,
                                  tickInterval: $parent.tickInterval(),
                                  y1suffix: '',
                                  y2suffix: '',
                                  graphID: 'red',
                                  filter: $parent.filter(),
                                  selectedOption: $parent.selectedOption(),
                                  url: Urls.get_ppc_dashboard_values(PageMeta.AccountToken)
                                }
                              }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Basicly the same thing, but I guess custom elements might present problems in a foreach?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I'll have to find out why foreach presents such a problem. :)

Comment: According to [this example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#note-combining-custom-elements-with-regular-bindings) you should be able to use custom elements inside a `foreach`...